# Get Data from Two api using RxJava

Tags: android, api, retrofit, rx-java, flatmap

I have two request of api

**// to get all products list inside specific category**

```
1. getCategoryProducts : Observable<List<CategoryProductsModel>
       class CategoryProductsModel {
        int categoryId ; 
        String sku ; 

    // sku is variable I used it to get the details for each product (name , images , colors , sizes , price ..etc

        }
```

**// to get product details by sku based on first api getCategoryProducts**

```
2.getProductDetails(var sku:String): Observable<ProductDetailsModel> 
       class ProductDetailsModel {
          float price ; 
          List<Images> images , 
          List<Colors> colors , 
          etc ... 
         }
```

first request is `getCategoryProducts` then `getProductDetails` based on the first request to get the `sku` for each product and pass it to `getProductDetails`

after I make the second request I want to add the data response in `ProductModel` to get finally a list of `ProductModel` to pass it to `recycler view`

```
 ProductModel 
{
 CategoryProductsModel mCategoryProductsModel ;
 ProductDetailsModel mProductDetailsModel ; 
}
```

I user RxJava to request API. How can I do that?

```
public void getProductsList() {

    getCategoryProductsObservable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap(new Function<CategoryProductsModel, ObservableSource<List<ProductModel>>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<List<ProductModel>> apply(CategoryProductsModel mCategoryProductsModel) throws Exception {
                    return getProductDetails(mCategoryProductsModel);
                }
            }).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this::fillProducts);



}





public Observable<CategoryProductsModel> getCategoryProductsObservable() {
   return Repository.Companion.getStoreInstance().getCategoryProducts(categoryId).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap(new Function<List<CategoryProductsModel>, ObservableSource<CategoryProductsModel>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<CategoryProductsModel> apply(List<CategoryProductsModel> mCategoryProductsList) throws Exception {
                    return Observable.fromIterable(mCategoryProductsList).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
                }
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());



}




@SuppressLint("CheckResult")
public Observable<List<ProductModel>> getProductDetails(CategoryProductsModel mCategoryProducts) {
    List<ProductModel> mList = new ArrayList<>() ;

    return Repository.Companion.getStoreInstance().getProductDetails(mCategoryProducts.getSku())
            .map(new Function<ProductDetailsModel, List<ProductModel>>() {

                @Override
                public List<ProductModel> apply(ProductDetailsModel mProductDetailsModel) throws Exception {
                    Log.d("mProductDetailsModel", mProductDetailsModel.getName());
                    ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel() ;
                    productModel.setProductDetailsModel(mProductDetailsModel);
                    productModel.setCategoryProductsModel(mCategoryProducts);
                    mList.add(productModel);


                    return mList;
                }
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

Answer (score 0):

list of operators you need: `switchMap()` `fromIterable()` and `toList()`. So your code will look like:

```
getCategoryProductsObservable()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .switchMap { listOfProducts -> Observable.fromIterable(listOfProducts)
                    .map { it.sku }
                    .flatMap { sku -> getProductDetails(sku) }
                    .toList()
                    .map { listOfProductDetails -> /* combine with listOfProducts to Model you need */ }
        }
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(this::fillProducts);
```

I used lambdas for shorter answer, can rewrite to `Function` style, but i guess it's self explanatory.

Comment: Thank you , Can you give me a full code that I want to get list of ProductModel ?

Comment: @MonisAttili does model `ProductDetailsModel` contains `String  sku` filed?

Comment: Yes it has sku the productDetailModel is response of api from magento to get details of products .

Comment: @GET("categories/{category_id}/products")
     fun getCategoryProducts(@Path("category_id") categoryId:Int): Observable<List<CategoryProductsModel>>
@GET("products/{sku}")
    fun getProductDetails(@Path("sku") sku:String): Observable<ProductDetailsModel>